# How to check if screen saver is running?

Tags: linux, x11, screensaver, kde-plasma

I have a script written in bash, which I need to take different route in case screensaver is currently running. This is Linux with Xorg and KDE. Script is called from cron, and it connects to DISPLAY=:0.

Any hint/idea how to check for state of screensaver?

Comment: Closest I can find is `xdg-screensaver status`, but it'll only tell you whether it is enabled, not when it is running. GNOME screensaver seems to have an unstable DBus interface that exposes this, but I'm not sure how to access it. KDE might have a specific way too, but someone else will have to find that. :)

Comment: I've done this using `dcop` in KDE 3.5 and `qdbus` KDE 4, but I don't have access to my home machine where the shell script resides right now. Checkout `kdcop` or `qdbusviewer` to inspect kdesktop; some trial and error should be enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently when running screensaver, aside from screensaver binary, there is also this process running:

```
/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kscreenlocker
```

So, I can simply do `ps uw -C kscreenlocker` and check results.

Answer (score 7):

If it is KDE4 you are running, you can use dbus to check if the screen saver is running:

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

or

```
$ qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

This works also for gnome, but they are known for not following FreeDesktop standards, so you have to use:

```
$ qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

Last but not least, you can check whether the standard X screen server is running using XScreenSaverQueryInfo() and checking the state field.

Answer (score 1):

On Gnome 40 you can use

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

It will print something like this

```
   boolean false
```